# Slick slide - slide position issue

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

http://35.186.164.237

There's a slick slide almost at the bottom of the page above with this configuration:

```
$('.module-testimonials').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    nextArrow: "<div class='right'><div class='icon-wrapper'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></div></div>",
    prevArrow: "<div class='left'><div class='icon-wrapper'><i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i></div></div>"
});
```

On all browsers the slides are incorrectly positioned. One of them you can't see at all. :((

Slick.js : http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: each slide is a different size?

Comment: Provide library which you had used

Comment: Updated with a link to the slick library.

Answer (score 0):

Try Replace width with height which you added in css

```
.module-testimonials img {
    /* width: 300px; remove this*/
    height: 245px;
}
```

Comment: It's gotten it closer! :D I've updated it. But the slick dots seem to be overlapping still on some...